# Invalid Credentials Error while fetching google plus user's data using google php client

Tags: php, android, google-plus, google-oauth

I am creating a basic android app which lets user login using google and fetches the access token. Then I send the access token to server which runs on php and fetch users info using that token from google.
Below is my code on android for fetching access token

```
public static void init(Context context, AppCompatActivity activity, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener onConnectionFailedListener){
        if(googleSignInOptions == null) {
            googleSignInOptions = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN).
                    requestIdToken(context.getString(R.string.google_web_api_key)).
                    requestScopes(new Scope(Scopes.PLUS_ME)).
                    requestProfile().
                    requestEmail().build();
        }
        if(googleApiClient == null) {
            googleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(context).enableAutoManage(activity, onConnectionFailedListener).
                    addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, googleSignInOptions).build();
        }
    }
//After login i call postGoogleSignin from onActivityResult
public static void postGoogleSignin(Watchable watchable, Intent data){
        GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if(googleSignInResult.isSuccess()){
            Log.v(Constant.TAG, "Google Login is successful");
            GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = googleSignInResult.getSignInAccount();
            String token = googleSignInAccount.getIdToken();// Access Token obtained
            }
            else{
                Log.e(Constant.TAG,"Error occured");
            }
```

I send this token to my server and try to fetch the users info.
Code for fetching users info

```
$gClient = new Google_Client();
            $gClient->setApplicationName('pixyfi');
            $gClient->setClientId($config['google']['appid']);
            $gClient->setClientSecret($config['google']['secret']);
            $privateKey=file_get_contents('googleAuth.json');
            $privateKeyPassword='notasecret';
            $scopes= array(
                'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login'
                );
$token = json_encode(array("access_token"=>$lptoken,"refresh_token"=>$lptoken,"token_type"=>"Bearer","expires_in"=>3600,"id_token"=>$lptoken,"created"=>time()));
            $gClient->setAccessToken($token);
$google_oauthV2 = new Google_Service_Plus($gClient);

            $gpUserProfile = $google_oauthV2->people->get('me'); //I get error here
echo "User Fetched as:".$gpUserProfile['id'];
```

Could you please tell me where exactly I'm mistaking?
I have followed same procedure for facebook and that works but I receive an invalid credential error.

Comment: What is the error message?

Comment: Invalid credential error